# sin(kx+2$\pi$) = sin(kx)

Tags: trigonometry

I'm reviewing the sinusoidal wave and I cannot figure out why the second equality holds here. Can someone explain? I know sin(x)=sin(x+2$\pi$) but I don't see how sin(kx+2$\pi$) = sin(kx).

[image]

Comment: Just substitute $kx$ for $x$ in the formula.  $x$ can be anything.

Comment: Substitute $kx$ to $x$ in $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin x$ (the latter equality is valid for all $x$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $2\pi$ is the period of the sine function,
$$\sin(\textrm{something} + 2\pi) = \sin(\textrm{something})$$
is always true, no matter what $(\textrm{something})$ is.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

The sine function has period $2\pi$ since when you go around a full circle, you're back where you started.

Comment: Thank you for your response.